# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{n+2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

> Deduce that $\displaystyle {n \choose 0}\dfrac{1}{1\cdot2}-{n \choose 1}\dfrac{1}{2\cdot3}+{n \choose 2}\dfrac{1}{3\cdot4}+...(-1)^n{n \choose n}\dfrac{1}{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}$

We know $\dfrac{1}{n+2}=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}t^{n+2-1}dt$

Now $\displaystyle {n \choose 0}\dfrac{1}{1\cdot2}-{n \choose 1}\dfrac{1}{2\cdot3}+{n \choose 2}\dfrac{1}{3\cdot4}+...(-1)^n{n \choose n}\dfrac{1}{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\bigg)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(k+1)}-\dfrac{1}{k+2}\bigg)$

$=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(k+1)}\bigg)-\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(k+2)}\bigg)$

$=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\int_{0}^1 t^{k+1-1}dt \space - \space \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k \int_{0}^1 t^{k+2-1}dt$

$=\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 t^{1-1}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-t)^k\bigg) dt- \int_{0}^1 t^{2-1}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-t)^k\bigg) dt$

$=\displaystyle  \int_{0}^1 t^{1-1}(1-t)^{n}dt \space - \space  \int_{0}^1 t^{2-1}(1-t)^{n}dt$

$=\displaystyle \large \beta(1,n+1)$-$\displaystyle \large\beta(2,n+1)$

$=\dfrac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(1+n+1)}-\dfrac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2+n+1)}= \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{n+2}}_{\text{which is exactly what I  proved}}$

PS @Chappers Thankyou all users for correcting one nasty mistake.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think there is an error? You have arrived to $\frac{1}{n+2}$ which is correct.

Comment: @Sil I corrected it now. Thanks

Comment: I understand you did get an answer you liked, but what I don't understand is why you would modify the question so it no longer makes sense. Think about the people who will view this question and answers in the future, they will not understand what was asked...

Comment: Actually @Sil I am preparing for an exam. So I keep these references for my future use. I know I should not have changed it but I did so in order to ease my revision process when I'll later look at it.

Comment: Note you don't need to let people know the question is answered: the site does this by displaying the number of answers and by marking the post green when you have accepted one.

Comment: No @PedroTamaroff users were saying this "I understand you did get an answer you liked, but what I don't understand is why you would modify the question so it no longer makes sense. Think about the people who will view this question and answers in the future, they will not understand what was asked... – Sil " In order to make others aware I did so.

Comment: I was refering to the content of the question. Originally you had the wrong proof and you asked where the issue was. Then after you got an answer, you changed the question so that there is no longer an issue in the proof. But that renders the question non sensical (and change in question title will not really solve that). I am not sure that using SE as a place for notes is a good idea (for example it might get deleted, you might want to check something like overleaf.com). But even then, there are ways to update the question without changing its meaning.

Comment: @Sil I understand. I will not do it henceforth. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your integral is incorrect: for $a>0$,
$$ \frac{1}{a} = \int_0^1 t^{a-1} \, dt, $$
so the integrals should be
$$ \frac{1}{k+1} = \int_0^1 t^{k} \, dt $$
and
$$ \frac{1}{k+2} = \int_0^1 t^{k+1} \, dt, $$
and then you get
$$ B(1,n+1)-B(2,n+1) = \frac{1}{n+2} $$
as expected.

Comment: (+1). Finally an answer that actually answers OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2} = \int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)\,dx $$
hence
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} &=& \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k\,dx\\ &=& \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{n+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{n+2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: thanks but I cannot understand where I was wrong! Why was it giving something else??

Comment: @Saradamani: because you wrote that $\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1}\,dx.$

Comment: Bad Bad Bad me! I corrected it thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t^{k} - t^{k + 1}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}t\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}t\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{1 \over n + 2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Multiply and divide by $(n+1)(n+2)$ to turn the question into $$\frac {1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom {n+2}{k+2}= \frac {1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[ \left(\sum_{k=-2}^n (-1)^k \binom {n+2}{k+2}\right)+(n+2)-1\right]=\frac {1}{n+2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively $$\dfrac{\binom nk}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\dfrac{\binom{n+2}{k+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Now set $a=b=1$ in  $$(a-b)^{n+2}=?$$